# PHP Foreach in_array() not working

Tags: php

I have a function comprising of:

```
function check_name($name)
{
    // Possibly slower than using regular expressions but since they're giving me grief, this function will scan a string for characters that aren't found in a human name 
    $invalid_characters = 0;
    $disallowed_chars = array_merge(range(0, 9), range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array(".", "'", "-"));
    // This array contains the characters I want to allow. If the character is not in the array, the counter is updated 
    $name = str_split($name);
    foreach($name as $letter)
    {
        if(in_array($letter, $disallowed_chars)==FALSE)
        {
            $invalid_characters = $invalid_characters + 1;
            $output[] = 1;
        }   
        else
        {
            $output[] = 0;
        }
    } 
    return array($invalid_characters, implode("", $name), $output);
}
```

The `$output` is just my way of testing it. Whenever I put a value into the form, say `aa!!\||\`, and call the function, I always get an entire array of 0s or 1s if I set the in_array check to true

Help would be greatfully apprchiated

Will

Comment: Why do not use for this a `preg_match`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand it why `!` seems it's in the array when not. Anyway, I've checked the `in_array`  documentation. The trick is to set the `in_array` to strict mode (add a third param as true).

```
function check_name($name) {
    // Possibly slower than using regular expressions but since they're giving me grief, this function will scan a string for characters that aren't found in a human name 
    $invalid_characters = 0;
    $disallowed_chars = array_merge(range(0, 9), range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array(".", "'", "-"));
    // This array contains the characters I want to allow. If the character is not in the array, the counter is updated 
    $letters = str_split($name);
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        if (in_array($letter, $disallowed_chars, true)) {
            $invalid_characters++;
            $output[] = 1;
        } else {
            $output[] = 0;
        }
    }
    return array($invalid_characters, $name, $output);
}
$string = "aa!!\\||\\";

$o = check_name($string);
```

Output is:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 2
  1 => string 'aa!!\||\' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 0
      3 => int 0
      4 => int 0
      5 => int 0
      6 => int 0
      7 => int 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This use $output_array instead $output,,

```
function check_name($name)
{
    // Possibly slower than using regular expressions but since they're giving me grief, this function will scan a string for characters that aren't found in a human name 
    $invalid_characters = 0;
    $disallowed_chars = array_merge(range(0, 9), range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array(".", "'", "-"));
    // This array contains the characters I want to allow. If the character is not in the array, the counter is updated 
    $name = str_split($name);
    foreach($name as $letter)
    {
        if(in_array($letter, $disallowed_chars)==FALSE)
        {
            $invalid_characters = $invalid_characters + 1;
            $output = 1;

        }   
        else
        {
            $output = 0;
        }
            $output_array = array_push($output);
    } 
    return array($invalid_characters, implode("", $name), $output);
}
```

Comment: You are using `$output_array` but returns with `$output`. Never inited the `$output_array`, the push has syntax error, because no array given as first param, so your code is totally wrong. Anyway, If you fix it, you will give back the same result as OP

Comment: Sorry for that replace   $output_array = array_push($output);  to                 $output_array = array_push($output,$output_array);